# Can not catch Vuex state change in my Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter, computed-properties

I have a Vuex store where I have a getter which works correctly and I can see the changes on the state. But if I call this getter as computed property in component it does not work. The value is still the same.

The store code looks like:

```js
mutations: {
  UPDATE_SERVER_FILTERS(state, payload) {
    this._vm.$set(state, 'serverFilters', payload);
    //state.serverFilters = payload;  // Both patterns work
  },
  getters: {
    serverFilters(state) {
      return state.serverFilters;  // This works fine
    }
  }
}
```

The component code:

```js
computed: {
  serverFilters() {
    return this.$store.getters[this.storeName + '/serverFilters'];
  },
}
```

Here is JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/camo/je0gw9t3/4/ which works fine. And it is a problem cause in my project it does not work. I am prepared to die...

How can I solve it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243734/discussion-on-question-by-camo-can-not-catch-vues-state-change-in-my-vue-compone).

Comment: You can start solving it by providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Putting a bounty on a question that cannot be efficiently answered won't really help.

Answer (score 2):

In the most bottom part:

```js
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#example',
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    changeFilters() {
      this.$store.dispatch(this.storeName + '/updateFilters');
      //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ there is no storeName 
    },
  },
});
```

The changeFilters method. You are using `this.storeName`, but there is no `this.storeName`! Just like the Child component, add `storeName: 'a'` to the `data()` then it should work.

https://jsfiddle.net/4yfv3w87/

---

Here is the debug process for your reference:

First open the Vue Devtools and switch to the timeline tab. And just click the button, you will see that there is no action is being fired. So the problem must be the one who dispatches the action. And then you will notice that the root component doesn't have a `storeName`.

So don't panic, just try to trace the code. It will only take a few minutes to find out the issue!

Comment: Having it all in a Codesandbox would be so much easier.

Comment: Thanks you are right. There was missing storeName, but in production code I have it right. As I fix it in JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/camo/je0gw9t3/48/ it works. It is not ok cause it is not working on production.

Comment: We must return to to question. The problem is that I can see the change in store and also in the store getter, BUT it does not propagete to the component computed property.

Comment: @Čamo just make a repro on codesandbox with the exact code. Will be faster for everybody. And try to think about any side effect-y code like middleware, global mixins and so on.

Comment: I can not do it. But I could send a zip file. Can I?

Comment: Not sure why you could not host it if you can send it as `.zip`. But yeah, let's go for the good old days of sharing code that way I guess.

Comment: Its because repo is public for everyone but zpi will have only person which I send to. I know you a little so I will trust you.

Comment: @kissu can you send me an email?

Comment: You can check my face pretty much everywhere yeah. And contact me on twitter too (check my profile). Otherwise, why would you not share the public repo? (my email is in my profile description too)

Comment: I send two emails. First contains Google drive link and second explains the repository and the problem.

Comment: @kissu how is it going? Is it running?

Comment: Nope, the project is not runnable with what you sent me.

Comment: :) I am sure it is. Error which you send is about wrong proxy. I send the right one in email.

Comment: @kissu what is you tax for hour? I really nned help with that.

Comment: @kissu did you look at it?

Comment: @Čamo yeah I've spent quite some time on it Tuesday. Checked some things that I thought may impact it. At the end, it's probably in the campaign store file, you may have a shallow copy while destructuring or alike. Didn't had more time to troubleshoot it further tho. Understanding the whole structure took me a bit of time and also, the fact that the whole object is not reactive at all was kinda a surprise. Could have moved faster but I've expected it to be a least a bit functional. Checking the apex of the namespace is probably the next step to go.

Comment: Yes it is quite big. I will send you some money for the time. Thanks, but if you can I would like to know what caused that surprise you wrote about.

Comment: I send it to you. Please take a look at it little deeper. You are surprised with that reactivity, but I am totaly down about it.

Comment: @kissu no progress in this issue? Can I hope or not?

Comment: @Čamo thanks for the Github donation. Meanwhile, I've spent quite a good amount of time on it already without finding the issue. I do also have other people to help + personal projects I do enjoy. Faster way would be to debug it by trying to replicating the whole thing, adding a bit of ESlint, splitting the code of the store and you'll probably figure it out. Sorry if I cannot help you more here.

Answer (score 0):

Computed properties might have problem to make an observer reference from returned value out of function. Instead of chaining getters and computed properties, why you don't use just getters or computed properties ? In my opinion, it's a bad practice to use them both, and I can't imagine a situation you need it. So if you need filter operations in many components, just make a getter and use getter in components instead of computed properties.

If you really want to chain them, try this:

```js
new Vue({
    store,
    el: '#example',
    data() {
        return {
        storeName: 'a'
      }
    },
    computed: {
      filters() {
          get() {
              return this.$store.getters[`${this.storeName}/getFilters`];
          }
          set(newValue) {
              this.$store.dispatch(this.storeName + '/updateFilters');
          }
      },
    },
})
```

Comment please if someone check it. I don't know are it works.